# MongoDB on ubuntu server with ufw firewall: connection timed out

Tags: mongodb

I am running MongoDB on an Ubuntu server with an ufw firewall. Even though I have whitelisted my IP in ufw and set the port in `/etc/mongod.conf` like so:

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,<IP>
```

I am not able to remote connect to my mongodb from my local machine's terminal by using: `mongo mongodb://something:something@IP:port/db`

The connection always times out and returns:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.0.5
connecting to: mongodb://<IP>:<port>/url?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2019-01-30T09:41:35.890-0800 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server <IP>:<port>, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to <IP>:<port> :: caused by :: Connection timed out :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:328:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

(I replaced the IP and port number with dummy text).

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong? The strangest thing was that in the early morning today this worked just once. Last night it did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Try Bind IP All bro, here's the code :

```js
mongod --bind_ip_all
```

I hope can help you.. :)